# Assignment of one category for each object, What's the best practice to achieve?

Tags: interaction-design, categorization, microinteractions

I'm designing a new product where the user can import their current apps to the system. In the system, there are 4 categories that represent the stages for product development: test, dev, QA, production. By default, all imported apps will be in the test environment.

A couple of limitations

- **Users can only assign each app to one stage**
- **Each app has multiple sub-apps**

Is there a common practice to design the interaction? What is the common mental modal?

I have two variations in mind.

[image]
Variation 1 User flow:

- User comes to this screen to classify the apps
- User can expand the tree of the left side and select the apps/sub-apps to be assigned to different groups
- Once the selects the apps/sub-apps/ sub-sub-apps, they can click on reassign to
- an app can belong to group A, whereas sub-apps can belong C, and sub-sub app to B

[image]
Variation 2 User flow:

- User has 4 groups(stages) and can select the group prior to adding the apps / sub-apps
- Once clicking on one of the groups, they can reassign the apps in the selected group

Comment: can the sub apps of an app be assigned to different categories? Could you mention the steps of the workflow for both the variations? That would make understanding the process easier

Comment: @harshikerfuffle, yes sub-apps can be in different categories. I added the user flow for each variation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best flow will be determined by what is the most common behaviour for the assignment of the apps, and there are some considerations here.

Firstly, if it more likely that the sub apps of a app are going to belong in different categories, then it would be a lot easier for users to assign an app into a specific category and have all the sub apps also be assigned to that category automatically. If this is not the case, or if we assume the worst case scenario, then it actually doesn't matter how the apps are listed because it might be quicker to pick all the apps that you want to assign to a category instead.

Secondly, if there is a specific order in which the apps are going to be assigned (e.g. chronologically as they are added or imported to your application) that will make a specific flow more logical, then you can also take advantage of this. There is no information on how the apps can be listed or sorted, but I assume that name and date imported will be available.

Thirdly, you have to look at the frequency of the operation and how many apps are going to be assigned at any given time. Since the number of categories is fixed and the number of apps can vary, it is possibly easier to anchor the flow based on the known constraints and work around the variability of the other factors.